# Executing a very large SQL file in Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.
I have a very large text file (a few hundred thousand rows) which contains INSERT statements which I wish to run.
What is the best way of executing this file? (I seem to be limited to a few thousand rows within the Management Studio / New Query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- sqlcmd
- separate to multiple files relative equal in size and parallel sqlcmd
- and the best - bulk load from the original datasource